# Minecraft Spigot Plugin - StringLists

Tags: java, yaml, minecraft

```
          List<String> bCmds = getConfig().getStringList("komendy-sprawdzanie");

           
          for (String bCmd : bCmds) {
              if(command != bCmd) {       
                  event.setCancelled(true);
                  player.sendTitle("§8[§bEasy§9Check§8]", "Jestes sprawdzany - Nie uzywaj komend", 5, 30, 5);
              }
              
          }
        }
```

```
- /reload
- rl
- /rl
```

Why it does not work?
It blocks every command.
I want it to block every command excluding commands in config

Comment: Help pls -_- idk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about what you wrote and what happens.

1. Loading a list of e.g. `["blocked command", "blockend command 2"]`.
2. Compare **each** element of list with the entered command `non blocked command`.
3. `non blocked command` is not `blocked command` -> block it.

Let's rethink your requirement: You want to block every command, which is not in your list. So, you proberly want a blacklist? This is very easy:

```java
for (String blocked : blockedList) {
   if (command == blocked) {
       event.setCancelled(true);
       break; // <- found a blocked one, no need to continue the search
   }
}
```

### Edit

Maybe you don't want to check if equals ... maybe you want to check the params too.
In this case, just compare the start of the command.

Put in your list `blocked`(or any other command, just the command). And then check for the start.

```
for (String blocked : blockedList) {
   if (command.startsWith(blocked) {
      event.setCancelled(true);
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: It does nothing ;c

Comment: komendy-sprawdzanie:
- /reload
- rl
- /rl

Comment: But only if i have one command in stringlist

Comment: How looks your code? What data you put into the list? What command was entered?